# Jest coverage acts wierd on single if statements using typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

It seems that jest is not able to cover a single if statement. This is a function that I want to test :

```
...  
load(): void {
    glob.sync('**/*.docs.json').forEach((file) => {
      const f = require(file);

      if (f.tags) this.doc.tags = f.tags;
});
```

I wrote the following test :

```
import path from 'path';

import Sample from './sample';

const mockedJsonConfigFile = __dirname + '/test.json';

jest.mock('glob', () => {
  return {
    sync: () => [mockedJsonConfigFile],
  };
});

describe('Sample test', () => {
  let sample: Sample;

  beforeAll(() => {
    sample = new Sample();
  });

  it('Should load file correctly', () => {
    const mockResolveFile = jest.spyOn(path, 'resolve');

    sample.load();

    let jsonFileCalled = false;
    // check if the json file is called
    mockResolveFile.mock.calls.forEach((c) => {
      if (typeof c == 'object' && c.includes(mockedJsonConfigFile)) {
        jsonFileCalled = true;
      }
    });

    expect(jsonFileCalled).toBeTruthy();
    expect(sample.doc.tags.length).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

It loads a fixture file containing an object of 2 tags :

```
{
  "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
}
```

So when I run the test, it tells me that the line 15 (if statement) is not covered but I don't understand why as my test specifies that it should have 2 elements into the tag array.

Any workaround for that ?

[image: jest]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't assert exactly what `load` does:

```
expect(sample.doc.tags.length).toBe(2);
```

It tests that `tags` is array-like but not what it's exactly and a condition it was assigned on.

Current `glob` mock isn't well-suited for this testing scenario because it's unconditional. It's better to make `glob.sync` a spy so implementation could be changed in different tests, then it can be mocked to return paths to different JSON fixtures. Alternatively, `glob.sync` mock can stay the same with JSON file being mocked with no fixture file.

It can be tested like:

```
jest.spyOn(glob, 'sync').mockReturnedValue([__dirname + '/test.json']);

...

const testJsonMock = { "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"] };
jest.mock(__dirname + '/test.json', () => testJsonMock);
sample.load();
expect(sample.doc.tags).toBe(testJsonMock.tags);

...

const testJsonMock = { "tags": null };
jest.mock(__dirname + '/test.json', () => testJsonMock);
sample.load();
expect(sample.doc.tags).toBeFalsy();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot for the explaination and for testing advices. I didn't know that you could return a value in the spyOn function. Also note that you will need to reset the modules as you are mocking 2 times the same file. Just add a jest.resetModules() in the beforeEach hook :)

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong. I tried to do both tests into the same describe method but mocking the same file without resetModules seems to use only the first declaration. In your case the second mock returns the same result as the first one